# Missing rows from Access query through ODBC

Tags: c#, ms-access, odbc

I'm trying to get some rows out of a query stored in a .mdb Access file into a DataSet in c#. This has always worked without any problem. 
[The query itself (SOME_QUERY_ON_FILE_MDB) is a result of joins and unions on other queries and tables stored in the same Access DB].

```
var conn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=C:\Temp\Report.mdb;Uid=Admin;Pwd=;");
conn.Open();

var command = new OdbcCommand(" SELECT * FROM SOME_QUERY_ON_FILE_MDB", conn);
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

OdbcDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command);

DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

conn.Close();
conn.Dispose();
```

As I run this code, I get 25 rows in `Dataset.Tables[0]`. But if I open the .mdb file in MS Access, there are 26 rows!

Also, if I debug and step through this code, or if I put the thread to sleep for a few milliseconds between opening the connection and before fetching the rows, all 26 rows are correctly retrieved.

What's the problem here? It seems like the query results are not ready when I execute the Select.
Is there some clean way to avoid that?

Comment: Are you using the most recent ODBC driver for MS Access?

Comment: Ok, ODBC uses odbcjt32.dll version 10.00 from 7/2016; And I'm facing exactly the same behavior on a test machine with ver. 6.01 from 6/2011.
Access file version (.mdb) from code `objAccess.CurrentProject.FileFormat` reads   `acFileFormatAccess2000` (9 as int). Could upgrading the Access file be an option? ty